Clarity's heatmap doesn't load nor scroll
I'm trying to use Clarity to monitor the performance of the new layout I designed for my platform and I'm having 3 problems

To see the heatmap of my page, I have to go in my Clarity's project page and filter by the page URL than go to heatmaps. If I only click in Heatmap first, then click to filter by URL, Clarity shows me another layout that's not my page.

If I go with the first way I've described above, Clarity just shows the clicks for a period of 1 day. When I try to view for a period of 3 or 7 days, the screen keeps loading and never displays the information.

I can't see the page scroll. Clarity fails to load; it seems as though my page has no scroll. I've read that Clarity has a limitation of 40k pixels, but my page is only a maximum of 1500px.


This way, I can't gain any insights from Clarity.
I appreciate any tips and possible solutions.
My project code is ky4ngj3ba2
And here's some screenshots:

Heatmap loaded with other design that's not my homepage (URL filtered is homepage)

Heatmap for the right page with a period of 1 day. Doesn't scroll and doesn't show me other periods like 3 or 7 days.

Heatmap loading forever. Not showing anything.


Heatmap loaded with other design that's not my homepage (URL filtered is homepage):

Heatmap for the right page with a period of 1 day. Doesn't scroll and doesn't show me other periods like 3 or 7 days:

